# How to Get Only Matched Result from An Array Field of Document in Mongo Using Spring Data

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am using `spring boot 1.5.1` and `MongoDB version 3.4.6` .

I have a mongo document Hotel which has a list of Review .

The `Review` class has property `userName`.

```
@Document
public class Hotel {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private List<Review> reviews;
```

I want to search all the hotel by Review userName.

My `HotelRepository` has `public List<Hotel> findByReviewsUserName(String userName);`

When I am calling with user 'Salman' -

```
List<Hotel> list = this.hotelRepository.findByReviewsUserName(user);
```

this method returns result like below :

```
[
    {
        "id": "59b23c39c70ff63135f76b14",
        "name": "Signature",
        "reviews": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "userName": "Salman",
                "rating": 8,
                "approved": true
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "userName": "Shahrukh",
                "rating": 5,
                "approved": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I want the reviews only of 'Salman' but it's also returning for others also.

What am I missing or how to do it?

**What I have noticed is that if a single review user matched it returns the whole list of reviews which I don't want, I want reviews I have searched by name.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The named query works as it should be. You are not explicitly saying that you want only a portion of document so query returns whole document. To achieve that *you cannot use named queries* **(see @alexefimov answer for using named queries with help of `@Query` annotation)** but you can use `MongoTemplate`beside of `MongoRepository`. to do that you have to make some changes:

First your repository should be like this:

```
public interface HotelRepository extends MongoRepository<Hotel, String>, MongoTemplateRepository {
    // You can continue to write your named queries here. Spring will create that.
}
```

MongoTemplateRepository:

```
public interface MongoTemplateRepository {
    // You will write your queries which will use mongoTemplate here. 
    List<Hotel> findByReviewsUserName(String userName);
}
```

For implementation of `MongoTemplateRepository` methods, you will write a new class. **The important** thing here is that you should named this class **your repository class name + Impl**. Otherwise spring-data cannot find where your methods implementation those defined in `MongoTemplateRepository`. So your implementation class's name should be `HotelRepositoryImpl`

```
public class HotelRepositoryImpl implements MongoTemplateRepository {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate; // we will use this to query mongoDb

    @Override
    public List<Hotel> findByReviewsUserName(String userName) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("reviews.username").is(userName));
        query.fields().include("reviews.$");
        return mongoTemplate.find(query, Hotel.class);
    }
}
```

Usage:

`hotelRepository.findByReviewsUserName("userName");`

As you can see in codes we can `.include()` or `.exclude`fields for the query. While you want to include just matched part of an array field, we use `$`operator with array field name.

**Conclusion:** You can still use spring-data well supported named queries and additionally if you need **aggregation** or some complex queries for sub documents that a named query cannot be built by spring, you can do it in your newly created mongoTemplate repository class. And you can access all of your repository methods from `HotelRepository`.

Answer (score 6):

Great answer from @barbakini, but that also can be done without creating custom repository implementation with Criteria, just 'describe' which fields you would like to get, where `0 - .exclude, 1 - .include(`

```
@Query(fields = "{ '_id': 0, 'reviews.$': 1 }")
List<Hotel> findByReviewsUserName(String userName);
```

Comment: can i ask for 1 problem, can i get just this list review as result (not return all the structure like: Object.review.Data...
 I just want to get the data as a list only. Can this possible

Comment: @NamNguyễn I think no - with providing Query, it is how Spring Data works. For that you could create your custom method implementation, and return whatever you want

Comment: i do create a new once herehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/55949195/mongorepository-get-only-specific-field-as-result But the problem is now with DBRef. The aggregate is not enough for the command and i don't know how to convert it to Spring-JPA