# Spring-Boot Mongo Db find all on query

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am using maven project with `spring-data-mongodb`. I created a model class my model class is

```
@Id
private String _id;

private String message;

private String possibleAnswer;

private boolean resolved;

private String percenteageMatch;
//Getters and Setters
```

Then i Created a an iterface with

```
public interface ContextRepository extends MongoRepository<ContextUnknown, String>{}
```

Now in my controller i want to find all the contextUnkown documents which are not resolved.

I know the query in mongodb is `db.getCollection('ContextUnknown').find({"resolved": true})`. 
I am unable to write it in to spring boot i tried adding Creria

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("resolved").is(false));
return contextRepository.findAll(query)
```

This is not working as findall doesn't take query as parameter, i tried the same thing with **BasicQuery** But still the same issue.

I want to get all the elements which are not resolved Is there any thing i should change so i can get all the elements based on query parameters.

Thanks in advance

Any help is deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the class you are using below code

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("resolved").is(false));
return contextRepository.findAll(query)
```

You need `MongoTemplate` to execute the `query`.

Do like this

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

List<ContextUnknown> result = mongoTemplate.find(query, ContextUnknown.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Query`, you have to use it with `MongoTemplate`. But because your query is simple, you can(spring-data can) easily build it with spring-data. Add one of these methods in your repository interface;

```
List<ContextUnknown> findByResolvedIsFalse();

List<ContextUnknown> findByResolved(boolean resolved);
```

Check [this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) to learn more about query creation using spring repositories. If you could not build query via spring repositories or you need some aggreation etc, You can combine `MongoTemplate` and spring repository in one interface. You can check [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46110743/how-to-get-only-matched-result-from-an-array-field-of-document-in-mongo-using-sp) to learn how to do it.